# OnClick String from array

Tags: android, string, random, onclick

I want to make an app with a long list of strings in a string-array. 
What I want to do is have a button la shows a random string when the button is clicked.
Could someone help please.
Thanks

Here is my code :

public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

```
public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/pagefonts.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.jamais);
    Button btn = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.je_nai_jamais); 
            tv.setText(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

I am getting errous here

tv.setText(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);

Comment: what is your current code?? please provide it here

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
    ((Button) v).setText(strings[i]);
}
```

where `strings` is your array of strings.

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
int i = Math.floor(Math.random() * je_nai_jamais.length);
((Button) v).setText(je_nai_jamais[i]);
   }
     });

        return rootView;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

First Generate A Random with in a range of 0 to length of your String . And Then Corresponding to random number Select String element.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int myValue = r.nextInt(max-offset)+offset;
yourTextView.setText(yourStringArray[myValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the string array from resources you want to do

```
String[] args = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourarray'sname);

Button button = (Button)findViewById(yourbutton'sid);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * args.length);
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(yourtextview'sid);    
tv.setText(args[number]);
});
```

Comment: TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/pagefonts.ttf");
        txt.setTypeface(font);
        Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    int number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * args.length);
    TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.jamais);    
    tv.setText(args[number]);
   }
     });

        return rootView;
    }
}

Comment: This can give you an array index out of bounds exception. Use `Math.floor` instead

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks but none of your codes worked for me so I try around and this one worked for me.
See :

```
Button next;
public FragmentJeNaiJamais(){}
Random rgenerator = new Random();
Vibrator myVibrator;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jamais, container, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/pagefonts.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);

    myVibrator = (Vibrator)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    final TextView iv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.jamais);

    next = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View V) {

             myVibrator.vibrate(70);
             String[] args = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.je_nai_jamais);
             iv.setText(args[new Random().nextInt(args.length)]);
             Typeface fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/artbrush.ttf");
             iv.setTypeface(fonts);


         }
    });
    return rootView;`
}
```

}

It may be helpful for some one